# Comment Permissions

Tags: users, comments

I am using advanced forums and I would like my site admins to be able to edit and delete forum comments.

The correct permissions are checked and the site admins can edit and delete comments by going into content->comments.

However, I would like to have a button on the comment that allows the admins to directly edit the comment.

Current these buttons exist for the original topic post, but not the corresponding comments.

For example, the admins have these options on a topic post.

[image]

However, on a comment the admins only have these options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/quickedit) module which allows content to be edited in-place.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `comment.tpl.php` in your theme directory and insert any link in there for any user. for example create link `<a href='www.example.com/commend/[comment_id]/edit'>edit</a>`

Notice that the comment id is available via `hook_preprocess_comment()`. you can set this ID in a variable and use it in the `comment.tpl.php`